# ArrayList is not Loading in Spinner

Tags: android, arraylist, spinner

Can u please tell me why my arraylist is not Loading in spinner. It is showing empty Spinner.im to populate spinner using arraylist ,And doing a service call;
Where did i do the mistake.
Here is my Activity;

```
public class CircleListActivity extends MWTActivity {

private ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
private Spinner state_spinner;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, MWT.Home_SCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.circlelist);

    showDialog(1);

    MWTWebService.circlelistServices(new IMWTListener() {

        @Override
        public void recieveVersionResponse(String resp) {

        }

        @Override
        public void receivedResponse(String resp, String id) {

        }

        @Override
        public void receivedResponse(String resp) {
            showDialog(1);
            System.out.println("rsp: " + resp);

            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(resp);
                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject
                        .getJSONArray("circleListForHording");
                arrayList.add("Select State");
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                    String state = (String) jsonArray.get(i);

                    arrayList.add(state);

                }
                state_spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.state);

                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                        CircleListActivity.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arrayList);
                adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                System.out.println("PP " + adapter.getItem(1));

                state_spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
                dismissDialog(1);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(String resp, int erroCode) {

        }
    }, LoginScreen.userNameNew.toString().trim());

    // if (Util.readNetworkConnection(CircleListActivity.this)) {} else {
    // ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
    // CircleListActivity.this,
    // android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arrayList);
    //
    // adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    // state_spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    //
    // }

}

}
```

Comment: are you sure, the server response is well defined and `arrayList` is actually filled with data?

Comment: yes i printed all the data,...and i m getting it in arraylist

Comment: are you getting any error?. have you checked it in logcat???

Comment: a smart break point and some debugging might help

Comment: No Error it is printing reponse perfectly..

Comment: Should i Call this All from the constructor..